# Python {} with nothing in it?

Tags: python

```
def __init__(self, specfile, listfile):
    self.spec=AssignmentSpec(specfile)
    self.submissions={}
```

I don't understand the meaning of this please help, `{}` with nothing in it??

Comment: Care to look at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries before writing here?

Comment: @BasicWolf What if the OP is a beginner and he doesn't know what to search for?

Comment: If you don't know what it is, you can't know what to search for.

Comment: My point is that one of the targets of the tutorial is answering these kind of "beginner's questions". People nowadays are so lazy that they don't even bother reading the tutorial. The next question may be "I don't understand the meaning of `x = (1, 2)`. I believe that answering those kind of questions if wrong if they are all *well-explained* in the official docs.

Answer (score 6):

Its the literal way of defining a dictionary. In this case, its an empty dictionary. Its the same as `self.submissions = dict()`

```
>>> i = {}
>>> z = {'key': 42}
>>> q = dict()
>>> i == q
True
>>> d = dict()
>>> d['key'] = 42
>>> d == z
True
```

Comment: I know it's for illustrative purposes but `dict()` shouldn't really be used in that form as it requires a name lookup, and can shadowed. So for efficiency and clarity... `{}` should be used for an empty dict.

Comment: It is strictly for illustration/explanation, thanks @JonClements

Answer (score 5):

It means that it is an empty dictionary.

In python:

> {} means empty dictionary.
>
> [] means empty list.
>
> () means empty tuple.

**Sample:**

```
print type({}), type([]), type(())
```

**Output**

```
<type 'dict'> <type 'list'> <type 'tuple'>
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by Paco in the comments, `(1)` will be considered as a number surrounded by brackets. To create a tuple with only one element in it, a comma has to be included at the end, like this, `(1,)`

```
print type({}), type([]), type((1)), type((1,))
<type 'dict'> <type 'list'> <type 'int'> <type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Be careful though: `type((1))` returns `<type 'int'>` ;-)

Comment: @Paco Of course, `()` is an empty tuple, `(1)` is considered as 1 with  in brackets. `(1,)` will be considered as a tuple.

Comment: Yes, just wanted to make sure. That might a bit tricky at start

Comment: @Paco Thanks for pointing that out. Added that also in the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

It defines a dict type object. If you are from C#/Java background it's same to:

```
IDictionary<xxx> myDict = new Dictionary();
```

or

```
Map<xxx, yyy> myMap = new HashMap<xxx, yyy> ();
```

or in C++ (loosely, because map is mostly a tree):

```
map<xxx, yyy> myMap;
```

xxx and yyy coz python is untyped language.